# how to run python script from javascript file?

Tags: javascript, python, html, google-chrome-extension, brython

I'm trying to run a python script in a chrome extension with brython and I'm stuck because of the content security policy.  The only tutorial I could find recommended I set up an html file like this:

```
<body onLoad="">
<iframe src="C:\\hello.py" id="frame" seamless="seamless" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</body>
```

but an error always pops up in the console saying:

```
"Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following 
Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe- 
inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required 
to enable inline execution."
```

I have this line in my manifest file:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; object-src 'self'",
```

but I assume it's not doing anything since people have said that the 'unsafe-inline" keyword is deprecated.

Is there any way to do this in a javascript file and not in the html, and is that a way to get around this problem? I'm really not sure what I'm doing here, so can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: You will not be able to run python like you doing. If you are writing some server side code, checkout python flask framework or similar.

Comment: Is there any way to execute the script in the chrome extension?  I was under the impression that you could convert the python to javascript code.

Comment: You will need python interpreter to run python code. You will not be able to launch python from chrome extensions. If you launch python from outside chrome extension can talk to external process.

Comment: yeah but I thought the whole point of brython is that it takes python code and outputs javascript code.  Is that not what brython does?

Comment: I am not expert with brython. brython will not be able run any python. But it can run python which is written using only brython apis. you have to write import statement from your html in order to execute python files.https://brython.info/static_doc/en/import.html